# What is the penalty for dying in SWTOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In many MMO's, there is a (sometimes huge) penalty for dying. For example in Lord of the Rings Online, there used to be a huge dread penalty, which made it very hard for you to win battles for half an hour. Your armour would be damaged as well, leading to high repair costs.

Now I was wondering, what are the penalties for dying in The Old Republic?

Comment: LotRO's "huge" penalty sounds pretty tame compared to EVE Online, the undisputed champion of punishing failure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a timer before you can resurrect, which increases if you die repeatedly in a short timespan.

- 1 death : 10 seconds
- 2 deaths: 30 seconds
- 3 deaths: 2 minutes
- 4 deaths: 10 minutes
- 5 deaths: 30 minutes

Free to play players can only resurrect (call medical probe) 5 times per character.

Your gear takes a minor durability loss as well, so there's a small credit cost that comes from repairing your gear.

I'm not sure exactly how long the time span is that those deaths have to occur in for it to ramp up, though. Note that you have the option to respawn immediately at a medical center, which given the almost non-existent cost of death, can effectively work as a teleport back to the nearest medical center for you when your normal cooldown is up and you don't want to have to run all the way back.

PVP deaths are handled differently, and force you to respawn at a medical center.

Comment: There are medical centers all over the maps, so the teleport trick won't work for long distances.

Comment: Bear in mind that it's only *items you have equipped* that take damage.  If you strip naked and die, you can respawn at a medcenter for zero penalty.  (Also, there is no durability loss for environmental deaths such as falling/lava, so in these cases of suicide you don't even need to remove your gear).